# Why is my jar not running?

Tags: java, packaging, executable-jar

I can run my program outside of a jar file, but I want to deploy it and run it as a jar.

This command works for running the .class file:

```
java -classpath .;./libs/mail.jar;./libs/jcommon-1.0.16.jar;./libs/jfreechart-1.0.13.jar;./libs/jxl.jar;./libs/ojdbc5.jar gdsreports/ReportsDriver
```

This is how I package my jar file:

```
jar -cfvm GDSReports.jar GDSReports.mf gdsreports/* util/* libs/*
```

My manifest looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: gdsreports.ReportsDriver
Created-By: Me
```

This is how I run my jar:

```
java -classpath .;./libs/mail.jar;./libs/jcommon-1.0.16.jar;./libs/jfreechart-1.0.13.jar;./libs/jxl.jar;./libs/ojdbc5.jar;./util;./gdsreports -jar GDSReports.jar
```

However, run I run the jar file, it fails to load all the libraries. This is what it spits out:

```
Error loading configuration file: config/reportConfig
Error loading configuration file: config/gdsIds
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/write/WriteException
        at util.ReportConfig.setupReports(ReportConfig.java:197)
        at util.ReportConfig.setup(ReportConfig.java:65)
        at gdsreports.ReportsDriver.main(ReportsDriver.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jxl.write.WriteException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
```

This is the expected output:

```
Error loading configuration file: config/reportConfig
Error loading configuration file: config/gdsIds
-------------------------------------
Running TimingReport with parameters:
        Filename: Reports/06-26-2012/TimingRptZL_06-26-2012.xls
        Brand: ZL
        Using production database: false
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at gdsreports.TimingReport.fillChartData(TimingReport.java:417)
        at gdsreports.TimingReport.fillReport(TimingReport.java:238)
        at gdsreports.TimingReport.run(TimingReport.java:131)
        at gdsreports.ReportsDriver.main(ReportsDriver.java:40)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-classpath` argument (and the `CLASSPATH` environment variable) are ignored when you use the `-jar` argument.

If a jar file depends on other libraries, you have two choices:

1. Use the `Class-Path` header in your `MANIFEST.MF` file to call out the other jars, or
2. Unpack the other jars and include them in your jar.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. Add some details to your question describing your attempt.

Comment: I was, needed to use Class-Path instead of Classpath. Will accept when the timer expires.